# How to make CAPTCHA with my own picture in drawable folder, in android studio?

Tags: android, image, random, captcha

I want to generate an image CAPTCHA (I have my own images) in Android Studio. Please help me, or show me the example, any response will be so appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You may try this https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement captcha in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938350/how-to-implement-captcha-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Visit this [link](https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA). Its a library for generating captcha in Android. Just add the dependencies into your build.gradel and Rebuild the project and you can add captcha where ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

To generate Captcha Code in Android use

**1> Generate Random Number**

public static String CapCodeGen(int limit) {

// add caracter to generate captcha Code

```
    String chars = "0123456789";
    Random r = new Random();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    buf.append(chars.charAt(r.nextInt(10)));
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        buf.append(chars.charAt(r.nextInt(chars.length())));
    }

    return String.valueOf(buf);

}
```

2> Set to TextView with captcha backgrount it will look like captach Image